# Jquery works when not in a function?

Tags: jquery

I'm a little bit confused right now, if I put this jquery on my webpage, everything works OK.

```
<script>
    $.get("/Recipe/SearchResult/", function (response) {
        $("#SearchResults").html(response);
    }); 
</script>
```

however, I am trying to have this run onclick on a button. so I put it in a function like this:

```
<script>    
    function Search() {
        $.get("/Recipe/SearchResult/", function (response) {
            $("#SearchResults").html(response);
        });
    };     
</script>
```

Using firebug, if I put a break on function Search{} {, when I click the button, it does break on that line. however, if I step over, it does not seem to run the jquery. it just goes to the end of the function for the next line and nothing happens.

edit: here is the line that has the button:

```
<button onclick="Search"  type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-search"></i> Search</button>
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Show the code where you call `Search`

Comment: `<button onclick="Search"  type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-search"></i> Search</button>`

Comment: Put the button code also

Comment: Do like that `<button onclick="Search()" type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-search"></i> Search</button>`

Comment: I tried with the () and with ();. Both with no success =/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It because your button type is submit, so after button clicked, form will post back and reload the page. try change it to type="button"

```
<button onclick="Search"  type="button" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-search"></i> Search</button>
```

Comment: As mentioned elsewhere, though, jQuery gives you (speaking to the original questioner here!) dead-easy tools to bind event handlers. Using the onclick attribute couples your markup to your JavaScript, which is considered a practice best avoided.

Comment: @GregPettit Thanks for the tip. I'm new to front end and did not know this was a better practice. What is the reasoning for this being a better practice? It seems to be it would be easier to figure out how a webpage works for someone else, since they could see if the element has onclick on mouseover etc and see the function that runs. I don't mean to be argumentative, just want to understand the reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$('.btn-success').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.get("/Recipe/SearchResult/", function(response) {
      $("#SearchResults").html(response);
   });   
})
```

Comment: @user1308743 if you are using jQuery you do not have to use(as a best practice) onclick. Try something like this code. Remove the onclick and just use jQuery.

Comment: Sample code is great, and this solves the problem of the submit handler, but without explaining what it does it's not as useful as it could be! Upvoted anyhow.

Comment: @DanielAranda Thanks for the tip. I'm new to front end and did not know this was a better practice. What is the reasoning for this being a better practice? It seems to be it would be easier to figure out how a webpage works for someone else, since they could see if the element has onclick on mouseover etc and see the function that runs. I don't mean to be argumentative, just want to understand the reasoning.

Comment: The best practice comes to make unobtrusive JavaScript. "Separation of behavior from markup", check this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Comment: What Daniel said. I didn't read the article (though I can imagine its contents!) but basically, you won't need to worry about whether someone can follow the code. It's the opposite of what you think: by having these all handled by the script itself, you never need to go to the markup thinking "Well how is this function being called?" because it's right there in the script itself. Separating the two will ultimately make your code EASIER to follow for those who use best practices.

Answer (score 2):

In your debugger, you would have to put a breakpoint on the line `$("#SearchResults").html(response);`.  You can't directly step through it because the callback function is called sometime later when the ajax request completes.  The asynchronous nature of the ajax call means you can't just step through it sequentially.

Even though the callback function looks sequential, it isn't executed sequentially.  The `Search()` function finishes and then sometime later the callback is called.

Comment: Absolutely. JavaScript is single threaded. Everything executes top-to-bottom, line-by-line. You could (using Chrome Dev Tools) step _into_ the method, but that would require (most likely) quite a few more steps into before you hit your code. Better and faster to break on the line you want to evaluate.

Comment: @Christopher - the point I was trying to make is that things don't execute top-to-bottom line by line when using an inline anonymous function as a callback to an asynchronous ajax call.  The end of the function executes before the callback does which is NOT top to bottom order.

Answer (score 2):

First of all your inline `onclick` attribute:

```
onclick="Search"
```

...is not calling the `Search` function. You have to put parentheses:

```
onclick="Search()"
```

> *"Using firebug, if I put a break on function Search{} {, when I click the button, it does break on that line. however, if I step over, it does not seem to run the jquery. it just goes to the end of the function for the next line and nothing happens."*

The `$.get()` function makes an *asynchronous* Ajax request, so the callback function that you supply is not supposed to run immediately, it will be called by jQuery later once the Ajax response occurs. Before that happens the rest of the `Search()` function will complete (though in your case there are no further statements in the function) regardless of how fast the Ajax response comes back. This is normal. Try putting a break point in that callback function, and/or use a `console.log()` statement in it.